# Newbie Cucumber scope question

Tags: cucumber

I am trying to check for the "style='width:60%'" bit in the html below

```
<div class='pers-ref-rate'>
  <div class='rating-type'>
    Reliability
  </div>
  <div class='type-reliable rating'>
    <div style='width:60%'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have got the line

```
And I should see a personal reliable rating of 60
```

and the following in my steps

```
Then /^I should see a personal (\w+) rating of (\d+)$/ do |rating_type, rating|
  with_scope("div.type-#{rating_type}") do
    page.should have_css('.rating', :style => "width:#{rating}")
  end
end
```

I am getting an error

```
RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError: expected #has_css?(".rating") to return true, got false
```

I stole the steps from another project and adapted it slightly (it was using ids not classes).

What have I done wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's looking for a

```
<div class="rating" style='width:60%'></div>
```

within the scope of

```
<div class='type-reliable rating'></div>
```

To make it work, either add the rating class to that div, or remove the css search for .rating in it.

hth

Comment: Thanks.  Normally I am just short-sighted and sometimes totally blind.